# Why are my transactional ActiveMQ messages being dropped instead of moving to the DLQ?

Tags: transactions, activemq-classic

I create my consumer (in C# using the NMS library) as so:

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(_mqServer);
        _con = factory.CreateConnection();
        _con.Start();
        _session = _con.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.Transactional);
        _queue = _session.GetQueue(_mqQueue);
        _consumer = _session.CreateConsumer(_queue, "someproperty = 'someValue'");
```

When I receive a message and don't call Commit on the session, it goes back into the original queue.  It then attempts redelivery 5 more times before being discarded.  Why is the message being discarded instead of being sent to a DLQ?!

Answer (score 2):

I know this was a long time ago so it probably won't help you, but one possible reason for this is that you're not sending persistent messages. If your messages aren't persistent, [ActiveMQ will discard them instead of sending them to the DLQ](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html#MessageRedeliveryandDLQHandling-Placenonpersistentmessagesontothedeadletterqueue).

Answer (score 0):

If it really is being discarded, it might actually be a bug. I have not tried to reproduce but during debug of an aplpication, i actually had a similar issue (forgot to commit transaction) and the messages did go to the DLQ. after retrying a couple of times.. so if you are sure they just get discarded, it might be a bug.

Comment: 100% sure of them being disregarded.  Also 100% sure I'm not committing.  It doesn't happen all of the time though, and I can repro.